# Unable to edit Input when using split() in angularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-scope

I have a nested JSON object which has array for one of the property in it.
The array items has ';'.

What I'm trying to achieve is to treat ';' as a delimiter and then split the array item further to make changes.

Once the changes are made join them back as it was before.
The problem is, i'm able to split the array item based on this delimiter but unable to edit it.
my JSON:

```
{
    name:"test1",
    xdata:["1;2;3","abhsad"]
}
```

here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/VYTQ6jvJ1bCKosRXh2Nt?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is going to be a little bit tricky, however it is still possible. You will need two `ngRepeat` loops with few `ngInit`/`ngChange` manipulations to initializing and updating stuff:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('DemoController', Ctrl);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.group = {
    name: "test1",
    xdata: ["1;2;3", "abhsad"]
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">

  <div ng-repeat="(i, val) in group.xdata track by $index" 
       ng-init="parts = val.split(';')">
    
    <input type="text" 
           ng-model="part" 
           ng-repeat="(j, part) in parts track by $index" 
           ng-change="parts[j] = part; group.xdata[i] = parts.join(';')">
  </div>

  <pre>group = {{group | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create model for every splitted value which will in turn update the model corresponding model upon changing the value in the text box and after which you could write a function that updates the `xData` values.

Here is a sample plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/0Rvi59pJJwwaw4zBMDD3?p=preview

Comment: This would work only for the first item in the array, since you've given array index [0]